# Did Shouko retain The Sword in the Grand Route?

Tags: aoishiro

During the Grand Route, while Shouko and Nami are trying to escape from Ba Rouryuu Shouko looses her arm from his attack. Later during the battle in the underground Nekata Sanctuary it is revealed that the reason why Shouko woke up without her arm missing was that The Sword had became her missing arm.

After the credits when Shouko and Nami are able to escape from the chaos and retain their forms Shouko seems to have her arm. however i am wondering, is this her arm regenerated or it is still The Sword?